# Wire methods in LWC vs Apex. Which one is faster?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to understand which one performs more efficiently: @wire methods in LWC or DML statements in Apex.

Do you prefer to finish your logic in LWC if everything that you need is supported as @wire methods, or do you anyway pass those logics to Apex class to make your LWC stay clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends on your use cases whether you want to use Wire or imperative Apex.

The wire method will definitely save time and lines of code as it is an out-of-the-box feature.
The wire gets called whenever an attribute value changes and on rendering of the component.
Apex methods need to be annotated with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true). Data returned are immutable. If you need to get fresh data, you will have to call refreshApex().

If you want certain logic to be executed on user inputs like on button click then you need to call the imperative apex which gives you more control over the flow.
You can call imperative apex on component load too in connectedCallBack.
You need to use imperative apex when working with objects which are not supported by user interface API.
It supports events like insert/update/delete which are not supported by the wire.

Both have there own benefits.

Comment: So you mean they basically work at the same speed, and it's a matter of... situation?

Comment: In my opinion yes, there might be a small variation. You can check it though by printing the seconds it took to execute in both ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare a wire method to a DML in Apex. Namely, wire methods can't perform DML. You instead need to use an imperative call. For that, we have functions like [`createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_create_record) so you don't need to write any Apex.

Every time you avoid writing Apex, you will naturally make your LWC run faster/more efficiently, because you're effectively calling direct API calls instead of going through the Apex layer. There's not a huge overhead in calling Apex, somewhere on the order of tens of milliseconds, but over the course of many calls, this can add up to a significant amount of time.

On the other hand, if you need to do things in bulk, you should not use the provided methods (e.g. `createRecord`) because there is a point where you'll experience a bottleneck in performance. If you need to create/update/delete records in bulk, Apex is almost certainly going to win when you are talking about dozens or hundreds (or more) records being modified at once.

There's nothing wrong with doing everything in Apex if that's the coding practice being used. The drop in performance, in most cases, won't be noticed in a typical-sized application. In certain industries, like video games, users very much care about the speed of every single frame. In an enterprise application, people are a lot more tolerant of a slightly slower UI, as long as it's manageable.

If you ask me, if there's two ways to do something, and both have about the same performance, but one is less code to write, I'm usually going to take the less-code option. When you write just one line of Apex, you're already committing to at least a dozen, because you now need a unit test to go with it, on top of whatever unit testing you intend to write in Jest for the UI code. The less-code option is usually the more-performance option as well, so avoid adding complexity if you can help it.